# struct constructor name precedence

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a struct like so... in C++11

```
struct StackOverflow
{
    int x;
    StackOverflow(){}
    StackOverflow(int x) { x = x; }
};
```

I know I should have written the latter constructor as `StackOverflow(int x) : x(x) {}` but I'm glad that I did not in this case, as I learned something:

The C++11 compiler did not *do the right thing* with the statement `{x = x;}`. Infact, the struct member `x` did not even get initialized (it had random values when I was debugging why my application was failing). And I did not receive a compiler warning.

Shouldn't this have worked?

Comment: looks like a `this` is missing.

Comment: The compiler absolutely _did the right thing_. You, however, did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters will shadow data members, *except* when being initialized in constructor initialization lists.

In `x = x` the `x` is shadowing the data member, and so it's assigning the parameter to itself.

```
StackOverflow(int x) : x(x) {}
//                     ^ ^
//                     | +-- parameter x
//                     |
//                     +---- data member x

StackOverflow(int x) { x = x; }
//                     ^   ^
//                     |   |
//                     +---+-- parameter x
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be using constructor-initialization-list which you seem to know already. So I think you just want to know why your code doesn't do what you *intend* it to do. Well the problem is the compiler doesn't  know your *intention* because it is not expressed in the program. You need to express your intention programatically as:

```
StackOverflow(int x) { this->x = x; }
```

The compiler need to know which `x` is which `x`. Using `this->x`, the compiler knows about your intension.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you introduced a new variable named `x` in the namespace of the constructor that hides your member.

The compiler *could* give you a warning, but it's not required.

There are three options:

- rename the parameter
- <sub>use the initialization list</sub>
- <sub>qualify the member as `this->x`</sub>

Use the first one, it's the most elegant. For this simple case, it doesn't make a big  difference, but think of a larger constructor, where you have to remember that `x` doesn't refer to the class member and that you have to write `this->x` when you want to use the class member.